# Meteorjs application integration with SpringMVC application

Tags: spring-mvc, meteor

We have a production running Spring MVC project. A requirement to develop a feature with MeteorJS(using MongoDB) in the same Spring MVC project. Can someone guide me if this is achievable to integrate and if yes, the best ways to achieve this.

Comment: Someone wants to take a page based technology and integrate with with a SPA technology? It sounds like they gave you no guidance on how they think it's all supposed to work. Was this a tech person or a manager who was told these were good technologies and thought it neat to combine them?

Comment: further, Meteor is full-stack solution. if you use an existing Java server to take the place of the Meteor server, then you don't really have Meteor anymore. you're left with a Blaze client, and then the question is "how does it get data from the server?" Or, do they mean running a full Meteor app alongside the Java server, and what does the integration of those stacks look like? You need to tell us more about what is required/expected, and what this mysterious feature is.